# How to find and remove duplicated values in the array?

Tags: php

I have already asked a similar question, but they seemed to misunderstand me. I promise I will learn to ask more detailed questions.
It is necessary to display this multidimensional array, but without repeating

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'cards1' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'A' 
          1 => string 'b' 
          2 => string 'c'
      'cards2' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'A' 
          1 => string 'e' 
          2 => string 'd'
      'cards3' => 
        array (size=3)
         0 => string  'A' 
          1 => string 'o' 
          2 => string 'l'
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'cards1' => 
        array (size=3)
         0 => string 'A' 
         1 => string 'b' 
         2 => string 'c'
      'cards2' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'A' 
          1 => string 'r' 
          2 => string 'c'
      'cards3' => 
        array (size=3)
         0 => string 'A' 
          1 => string 'bbb' 
          2 => string 'yyy'
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'cards1' => 
        array (size=3)
         0 => string 'A' 
          1 => string 'bbb' 
          2 => string 'ggg'
      'cards2' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'A' 
      'cards3' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'A'
```

result

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'cards1' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string  'A' 
          1 => string 'b' 
          2 => string 'c'
      'cards2' => 
        array (size=2)
          1 => string 'e' 
          2 => string 'd'
      'cards3' => 
        array (size=2)
          1 => string 'o' 
          2 => string 'l'
 1 => 
    array (size=3)
    'cards1' => 
      array (size=1)
          0 => string  'A' 
      'cards2' => 
        array (size=1)
          1 => string 'r' 
      'cards3' => 
        array (size=3)
          1 => string 'bbb' 
          2 => string 'yyy'
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
     'cards1' => 
      array (size=1)
          0 => string  'WWW' 
        array (size=3)
          2 => string 'ggg'
      'cards2' => 

      'cards3' =>
```

There should be no repetition in the array.
in the array can be 2 and 4 and 10 elements.

and array size can be 4 , 10 , 100

Comment: But it is written on what index. he deletes where the mail is, but I need to pass on all three

Comment: If you want us to help then make it easy for us to help. Posting print_r or var_dumps of an array is not making it easy for us. Use var_exprot or json_encode.

Comment: Just put each value you output into a flat array, and then before you output the next value, check if it is contained in that flat array already using `in_array` …?

Comment: So I tried, but it does not work
`
    $has = array();
            $output = array();
            foreach ( $newUser as $data ){
                if ( !in_array($data['cards1'][1], $has) )
                {
                    $has[] = $data['cards1'][1];
                    $output[] = $data;
                }
            }
`

Comment: there one by one, and I need so that in 1 2 and in cards1 cards2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a basic foreach loop. Loop over all values and maintain an associative array where the values like 'A','b' ..etc are keys of this associative array. I call it `$set` in my code. Now, if the value exists in the `$set` with [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) check, unset it, else add the current value in iteration to set. Note that I have used `&` to edit the same reference of the array rather than a cloned one.

```
<?php

$arr = [
   [
        'cards1' => [
            'A',
            'b',
            'c'
        ],
        'cards2' => [
            'A',
            'e',
            'd'
        ],
        'cards3' => [
            'A',
            'o',
            'l'
        ]
    ],
    [
         'cards1' => [
            'A',
            'b',
            'c'
        ],
        'cards2' => [
            'A',
            'r',
            'c'
        ],
        'cards3' => [
            'A',
            'bbb',
            'yyy'
        ]
    ],
    [
         'cards1' => [
            'A',
            'bbb',
            'ggg'
        ],
        'cards2' => [
            'A',
        ],
        'cards3' => [
            'A',
        ]    
    ]
];

$set = [];

foreach($arr as &$data){
    foreach($data as &$cards){
        foreach($cards as $index => $value){
            if(isset($set[$value])) unset($cards[$index]);
            else  $set[$value] = true;
        }
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/5vp0n

**Update:**

```
<?php

$arr = [
   [
        'cards1' => [
            'A',
            'b',
            'c'
        ],
        'cards2' => [
            'A',
            'e',
            'd'
        ],
        'cards3' => [
            'A',
            'o',
            'l'
        ]
    ],
    [
         'cards1' => [
            'A',
            'b',
            'c'
        ],
        'cards2' => [
            'A',
            'r',
            'c'
        ],
        'cards3' => [
            'A',
            'bbb',
            'yyy'
        ]
    ],
    [
         'cards1' => [
            'B',
            'bbb',
            'B'
        ],
        'cards2' => [
            'B',
        ],
        'cards3' => [
            'B',
        ]    
    ]
];

$set = [];
$except = [];


foreach($arr as $data){
    foreach($data as $key => $cards){
        if($key === 'cards1'){
            $except[$data[$key][0]] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

foreach($arr as &$data){
    foreach($data as $key => &$cards){
        foreach($cards as $index => $value){
            if(isset($set[$value]) && !isset($except[$value])) unset($cards[$index]);
            else  $set[$value] = true;
        }
    }
}


print_r($arr);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/14LHh

As discussed in the comments about the new requirement, we first collect all values of `$cards1[0]` in each sub array and store them in `$except` as keys. Now, we iterate over the array values again and unset only those which aren't found in `$except` and which are duplicates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_unique($your_array)`. It will filter duplicated values. Hope you find the best result.

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code
Suppose your array is $result_arr

```
$final_arr = $val_arr = [];
foreach ($resul_arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $new_arr = [];
        foreach ($v as $s) {
            if (!in_array($s, $val_arr)) {
                $new_arr[] = $s;
            }
            $val_arr[] = $s;
        }
        $final_arr[$key][$k] = $new_arr;
        $val_arr = array_unique($val_arr);
    }
}
echo "Final Array is";
var_dump($final_arr);
```

Comment: Cannot use [] for reading $final_arr = $val_arr [];

Comment: Just updated the answer. Forgot to add "="

Comment: no, it does not work, it still leaves repeated values

Comment: @josef I edited again there is small change. Could you please try again with edited code?

Comment: oooooo it's works, thanks very match . )))and how can I do that to zero index he did not take into account, please. 
so that it does not touch anywhere cards1[0]

Comment: can you mark my answer as correct if it works for you? 
Also I'm not getting zero index, you mean you want all elements are "cards1" ?

Comment: no no, you didn't understand. I here thought and understood that everything should be compared and deleted repetition EXCEPT cards1[0]